# How to put overlay on hover to flex item in flex container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

This is my code. I want to put the gray color overlay, over the content of each flexItem. The layer must be over the image also. I can't find a solution, anyone has some idea?

I try with relative position on flexCont, and absolute on flexItem overlay but nothing to do.

I have the function in js that applay an overlay class on hover, and remove it if you dont hover more

```js
$('.flexItem').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).addClass( 'overlay' );
            console.log('hover')
          }, function() {
          $(this).removeClass( 'overlay' ); 
            console.log('no hover')
          }
    );
```

```css
.flexCont{
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
 display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.flexContO{
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
 display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.flexContO>div{
    width:50%;
}

.flexCont .flexItem{
    flex: 1 1 25%;
}

.flexItem{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.overlay{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /*dim the background*/
    position: relative;
z-index:999!important;
  }

.flexItemV{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.flexItemO{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;  
}
.flexItemO>div{
    width:50%;
}

.flexItem1{
   height:375px;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   text-align:center;
   padding:20px;
}

.flexItem2>img{
    width: 100%;z-index:99!important;
}

.flexItemV1{

}
.flexItemV2{
    
}

.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flexCont">
    <div class="flexItem">
       <div class="flexItem1">
          <p>Place</p>
          <h3>u &amp; d 4</h3>
          <a href="http//link/u-d/">sometext bla bla </a><br><a href="http//link/u-d/"><i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
       </div>
       <div class="flexItem2"><img src="https://meme.xyz/uploads/posts/t/l-1229-the-two-states-of-every-programmer.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
       <div class="flexItem2"><img src="https://meme.xyz/uploads/posts/t/l-1229-the-two-states-of-every-programmer.jpg"></div>
       <div class="flexItem1">
          <p>Place</p>
          <h3>d &amp; u 3</h3>
          <a href="http//link/d-u/">sometext bla bla </a><br><a href="http//link/d-u/"><i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
       <div class="flexItem1">
          <p>Place</p>
          <h3>d &amp; u 2</h3>
          <a href="http//link/matrimonio-test2/">sometext bla bla </a><br><a href="http//link/matrimonio-test2/"><i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
       </div>
       <div class="flexItem2"><img src="https://meme.xyz/uploads/posts/t/l-1229-the-two-states-of-every-programmer.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
       <div class="flexItem2"><img src="https://meme.xyz/uploads/posts/t/l-1229-the-two-states-of-every-programmer.jpg"></div>
       <div class="flexItem1">
          <p>Place</p>
          <h3>u &amp; d 1</h3>
          <a href="http//link/matrimonio-test/">sometext bla bla </a><br><a href="http//link/matrimonio-test/"><i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You can add `z-index` to `<img>` tag and `.overlay` class.

Comment: I did it also here in the code, it doesn't works

Comment: Check below my answer!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use below updated code:

```js
$('.flexItem').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass( 'overlay' );
    $(this).find('img').css('opacity', '0.6');
    //console.log('hover')
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass( 'overlay' ); 
    $(this).find('img').css('opacity', '1');
    //console.log('no hover')
  }
);
```

```css
.flexCont{
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
   display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.flexContO{
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
   display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.flexContO>div{
    width:50%;
}

.flexCont .flexItem{
    flex: 1 1 25%;
}

.flexItem{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.overlay{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /*dim the background*/
    position: relative;
    z-index:999!important;
}

.flexItemV{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.flexItemO{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;  
}
.flexItemO>div{
    width:50%;
}

.flexItem1{
   height:375px;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   text-align:center;
   padding:20px;
}

.flexItem2>img{
    width: 100%;
    z-index:99!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flexCont">
    <div class="flexItem">
       <div class="flexItem1">
          <p>Place</p>
          <h3>u &amp; d 4</h3>
          <a href="http//link/u-d/">sometext bla bla </a><br><a href="http//link/u-d/"><i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
       </div>
       <div class="flexItem2"><img src="https://meme.xyz/uploads/posts/t/l-1229-the-two-states-of-every-programmer.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
       <div class="flexItem2"><img src="https://meme.xyz/uploads/posts/t/l-1229-the-two-states-of-every-programmer.jpg"></div>
       <div class="flexItem1">
          <p>Place</p>
          <h3>d &amp; u 3</h3>
          <a href="http//link/d-u/">sometext bla bla </a><br><a href="http//link/d-u/"><i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
       <div class="flexItem1">
          <p>Place</p>
          <h3>d &amp; u 2</h3>
          <a href="http//link/matrimonio-test2/">sometext bla bla </a><br><a href="http//link/matrimonio-test2/"><i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
       </div>
       <div class="flexItem2"><img src="https://meme.xyz/uploads/posts/t/l-1229-the-two-states-of-every-programmer.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
       <div class="flexItem2"><img src="https://meme.xyz/uploads/posts/t/l-1229-the-two-states-of-every-programmer.jpg"></div>
       <div class="flexItem1">
          <p>Place</p>
          <h3>u &amp; d 1</h3>
          <a href="http//link/matrimonio-test/">sometext bla bla </a><br><a href="http//link/matrimonio-test/"><i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don’t have any actual “overlay” here, you are just setting the background of the `.flexItem` element *itself*. So of course the *background color* you are setting does not “overlay” the image, because the image is *content* of the element, and the *background* is, well, in the back ...

You can simply use a pseudo element, positioned over the rest of the element, instead:

```js
$('.flexItem').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).addClass( 'overlay' );
            console.log('hover')
          }, function() {
          $(this).removeClass( 'overlay' ); 
            console.log('no hover')
          }
    );
```

```css
.flexCont{
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
 display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.flexContO{
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
 display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.flexContO>div{
    width:50%;
}

.flexCont .flexItem{
    flex: 1 1 25%;
}

.flexItem{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
}
.overlay::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5); /*dim the background*/
  }

.flexItemV{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.flexItemO{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;  
}
.flexItemO>div{
    width:50%;
}

.flexItem1{
   height:375px;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   text-align:center;
   padding:20px;
}

.flexItem2>img{
    width: 100%;z-index:99!important;
}

.flexItemV1{

}
.flexItemV2{
    
}

.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flexCont">
    <div class="flexItem">
       <div class="flexItem1">
          <p>Place</p>
          <h3>u &amp; d 4</h3>
          <a href="http//link/u-d/">sometext bla bla </a><br><a href="http//link/u-d/"><i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
       </div>
       <div class="flexItem2"><img src="https://meme.xyz/uploads/posts/t/l-1229-the-two-states-of-every-programmer.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
       <div class="flexItem2"><img src="https://meme.xyz/uploads/posts/t/l-1229-the-two-states-of-every-programmer.jpg"></div>
       <div class="flexItem1">
          <p>Place</p>
          <h3>d &amp; u 3</h3>
          <a href="http//link/d-u/">sometext bla bla </a><br><a href="http//link/d-u/"><i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
       <div class="flexItem1">
          <p>Place</p>
          <h3>d &amp; u 2</h3>
          <a href="http//link/matrimonio-test2/">sometext bla bla </a><br><a href="http//link/matrimonio-test2/"><i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
       </div>
       <div class="flexItem2"><img src="https://meme.xyz/uploads/posts/t/l-1229-the-two-states-of-every-programmer.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
       <div class="flexItem2"><img src="https://meme.xyz/uploads/posts/t/l-1229-the-two-states-of-every-programmer.jpg"></div>
       <div class="flexItem1">
          <p>Place</p>
          <h3>u &amp; d 1</h3>
          <a href="http//link/matrimonio-test/">sometext bla bla </a><br><a href="http//link/matrimonio-test/"><i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: (And if you only need to manipulate the element itself and stuff that is inside it, this would not need JavaScript at all, but could be done purely in CSS.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the overlay as a separate element inside `.flexItem`

```js
$('.flexItem').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).find('.overlay').show();
  },
  function() {
    $(this).find('.overlay').hide();
  }
);
```

```css
.flexCont {
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flexContO {
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flexContO>div {
  width: 50%;
}

.flexCont .flexItem {
  flex: 1 1 25%;
}

.flexItem {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative; /* Added */
}

.overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute; /* Changed from relative */
  top: 0; /* Added */
  left: 0; /* Added */
  width: 100%; /* Added */
  height: 100%; /* Added */
  display: none; /* Added */
}

.flexItemV {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flexItemO {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flexItemO>div {
  width: 50%;
}

.flexItem1 {
  height: 375px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.flexItem2>img {
  width: 100%;
}

.flexItemV1 {}

.flexItemV2 {}

.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flexCont">
  <div class="flexItem">
    <div class="flexItem1">
      <p>Place</p>
      <h3>u &amp; d 4</h3>
      <a href="http//link/u-d/">sometext bla bla </a><br><a href="http//link/u-d/"><i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem2"><img src="https://meme.xyz/uploads/posts/t/l-1229-the-two-states-of-every-programmer.jpg"></div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexItem">
    <div class="flexItem2"><img src="https://meme.xyz/uploads/posts/t/l-1229-the-two-states-of-every-programmer.jpg"></div>
    <div class="flexItem1">
      <p>Place</p>
      <h3>d &amp; u 3</h3>
      <a href="http//link/d-u/">sometext bla bla </a><br><a href="http//link/d-u/"><i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexItem">
    <div class="flexItem1">
      <p>Place</p>
      <h3>d &amp; u 2</h3>
      <a href="http//link/matrimonio-test2/">sometext bla bla </a><br><a href="http//link/matrimonio-test2/"><i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem2"><img src="https://meme.xyz/uploads/posts/t/l-1229-the-two-states-of-every-programmer.jpg"></div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexItem">
    <div class="flexItem2"><img src="https://meme.xyz/uploads/posts/t/l-1229-the-two-states-of-every-programmer.jpg"></div>
    <div class="flexItem1">
      <p>Place</p>
      <h3>u &amp; d 1</h3>
      <a href="http//link/matrimonio-test/">sometext bla bla </a><br><a href="http//link/matrimonio-test/"><i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In all other solutions, you link is not clickable, here is complete solution where grey dimmer comes over image and gives actual effect you exactly wanted.

```js
$(".flexItem").mouseover(function(){
    $(".overlay-items").css("height", $(".flexItem").outerHeight());
  });
```

```css
.flexCont{
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.flexContO{
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.flexContO>div{
    width:50%;
}

.flexCont .flexItem{
    flex: 1 1 25%;
}

.flexItem{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
}
.overlay-items{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /*dim the background*/
    position: relative;
    z-index:999!important;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
  }

.flexItemV{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.flexItemO{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;  
}
.flexItemO>div{
    width:50%;
}

.flexItem1{
   height:375px;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   text-align:center;
   padding:20px;
   z-index: 9999999;
}

.flexItem2>img{
    width: 100%;z-index:99!important;
}
.flexItem:hover > .overlay-items {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flexCont">
    <div class="flexItem">
    <div class="overlay-items"></div>
       <div class="flexItem1">
          <p>Place</p>
          <h3>u &amp; d 4</h3>
          <a href="http//link/u-d/">sometext bla bla </a><br><a href="http//link/u-d/"><i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
       </div>
       <div class="flexItem2"><img src="https://meme.xyz/uploads/posts/t/l-1229-the-two-states-of-every-programmer.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
    <div class="overlay-items"></div>
       <div class="flexItem2"><img src="https://meme.xyz/uploads/posts/t/l-1229-the-two-states-of-every-programmer.jpg"></div>
       <div class="flexItem1">
          <p>Place</p>
          <h3>d &amp; u 3</h3>
          <a href="http//link/d-u/">sometext bla bla </a><br><a href="http//link/d-u/"><i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
    <div class="overlay-items"></div>
       <div class="flexItem1">
          <p>Place</p>
          <h3>d &amp; u 2</h3>
          <a href="http//link/matrimonio-test2/">sometext bla bla </a><br><a href="http//link/matrimonio-test2/"><i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
       </div>
       <div class="flexItem2"><img src="https://meme.xyz/uploads/posts/t/l-1229-the-two-states-of-every-programmer.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
    <div class="overlay-items"></div>
       <div class="flexItem2"><img src="https://meme.xyz/uploads/posts/t/l-1229-the-two-states-of-every-programmer.jpg"></div>
       <div class="flexItem1">
          <p>Place</p>
          <h3>u &amp; d 1</h3>
          <a href="http//link/matrimonio-test/">sometext bla bla </a><br><a href="http//link/matrimonio-test/"><i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can use the `after` pseudo element to style this. Check this

```js
$('.flexItem').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass( 'overlay' );
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass( 'overlay' ); 
  }
);
```

```css
.flexCont {
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.flexContO {
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.flexContO>div {
    width: 50%;
}

.flexCont .flexItem {
    flex: 1 1 25%;
}

.flexItem {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.overlay {
    /*dim the background*/
    position: relative;
}

.overlay:after {
    content: "";
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.flexItemV {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.flexItemO {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.flexItemO>div {
    width: 50%;
}

.flexItem1 {
    height: 375px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

.flexItem2>img {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flexCont">
    <div class="flexItem">
       <div class="flexItem1">
          <p>Place</p>
          <h3>u &amp; d 4</h3>
          <a href="http//link/u-d/">sometext bla bla </a><br><a href="http//link/u-d/"><i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
       </div>
       <div class="flexItem2"><img src="https://meme.xyz/uploads/posts/t/l-1229-the-two-states-of-every-programmer.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
       <div class="flexItem2"><img src="https://meme.xyz/uploads/posts/t/l-1229-the-two-states-of-every-programmer.jpg"></div>
       <div class="flexItem1">
          <p>Place</p>
          <h3>d &amp; u 3</h3>
          <a href="http//link/d-u/">sometext bla bla </a><br><a href="http//link/d-u/"><i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
       <div class="flexItem1">
          <p>Place</p>
          <h3>d &amp; u 2</h3>
          <a href="http//link/matrimonio-test2/">sometext bla bla </a><br><a href="http//link/matrimonio-test2/"><i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
       </div>
       <div class="flexItem2"><img src="https://meme.xyz/uploads/posts/t/l-1229-the-two-states-of-every-programmer.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flexItem">
       <div class="flexItem2"><img src="https://meme.xyz/uploads/posts/t/l-1229-the-two-states-of-every-programmer.jpg"></div>
       <div class="flexItem1">
          <p>Place</p>
          <h3>u &amp; d 1</h3>
          <a href="http//link/matrimonio-test/">sometext bla bla </a><br><a href="http//link/matrimonio-test/"><i class="x-icon x-icon-arrow-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I can't hide it, I have to change not here opacity but to put over it a color.